# What is the best approach to collect result from Spark Dataset?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have a dataset of 2 fields/columns, `col1` and `col2`, and both are `Array[String]` type. I am collecting the distinct elements from `col1` in sorted order for each element of `_dArr` and keeping only the first element in the List named `_list`. The problem is `val arr = _ds.take(1)(0)`, which takes a lot of time. Is there any better approach I can use to make the code more efficient. I also took an empty dataset and did union to add new rows, which I was getting as `_ds` from each for loop so that later I can do `collect` on that resultant dataset to get the result as `List[Array[String]]`. But it also took a lot of time.

```
case class ColFields(fields: Array[String])
var _dArr = null: Array[String]
var _list = List[ClassFields]()

    _dArr.foreach(x => {
      val _ds = df.select("col1")
        .where(array_contains(df("col2"), x))
        .withColumn("col1", explode(col("col1")))
        .agg(sort_array(collect_set("col1")).alias("col1")).as[Array[String]]
        .cache()

      val arr = _ds.take(1)(0)
      // val arr = _ds.collect()(0) // Does not make any performance difference.
      distPredDS.unpersist()

      _list ::= ColFields(arr)
    })
```

Sample input:

```
_dArr = Array[x, y, w]

col1         col2
------------------
[a, b]      [w, x]
[a, d]      [x, y]
[c, d, f]   [y]
[h]         [w]
```

Output:

```
List[Array[a, b, d], Array[a, c, d, f], Array[a, b, h]]
```

or,

```
List[List[a, b, d], List[a, c, d, f], List[a, b, h]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I understood, you are trying to find if col2 contains any of the element from dArray, if yes, then get the first element sorted from col1 into a list.

```
    val dArr = Array("x","y","z")
    val df = Seq((Array("s","x","w"),Array("a","x")),(Array("v","d","e"),Array("b","z")),(Array("a","b","c"),Array("f","d"))).toDF("col1","col2")
   def checkValues(arr: Array[String]) = udf((col1: Seq[String], col2: Seq[String]) => { if (col2.exists(arr.contains)) col1.toList.sortWith(_ < _).head else ""})
   df.withColumn("col1_first", checkValues(dArr)($"col1",$"col2")).select($"col1_first").collectAsList
```

Here I am passing col1 & col2 to a UDF where it compared col2 against the arr and getting the first element of col1 after sorting it. You can then filter the nonempty value and collectAsList.

Let me know if it works, otherwise please provide more information including the data samples that you are expecting.

I have modified, but explode seems a costly operation. See if it helps with your dataset,

```
val dArr = Array("x","y","w")
val df = Seq((Array("a","b"),Array("w","x")),(Array("a","d"),Array("x","y")),(Array("c","d","f"),Array("x","y")),(Array("h"),Array("w"))).toDF("col1","col2")
def checkValues(arr: Array[String]) = udf((col1: Seq[String], col2: Seq[String]) => { arr.foldLeft(Array[String]()){case(acc, elem) => {if (col2.contains(elem)) acc :+ elem else acc}}})
val df_1 = df.withColumn("arrValues", explode(checkValues(dArr)($"col1",$"col2")))
df_1.select($"arrValues",explode($"col1").as("col1")).groupBy($"arrValues").agg(collect_set($"col1").as("col1_list")).show
```

Comment: For each element in `dArr `, say for x, it will pull out, let's say `[s,x,w]`and `[x,y,s]` from `col1` and then it will find the distinct elements from those two arrays as `List[s,w,x,y]` in sorted order. similarly, it will find the distinct elements as List for other values of `dArr ` and added those distinct elements List into another List or Array.